# How does php strtotime handle last sunday

Tags: php, strtotime

When I try to fetch a timestamp for X days after last sunday, I get an odd result.

```
echo date("Y-m-d\n", strtotime("2014-05-11 last sunday +5 days")); => 2014-05-09
echo date("Y-m-d\n", strtotime("2014-05-11 last sunday +6 days")); => 2014-05-10
echo date("Y-m-d\n", strtotime("2014-05-11 last sunday +7 days")); => 2014-05-18
echo date("Y-m-d\n", strtotime("2014-05-11 last sunday +8 days")); => 2014-05-19
```

Why does it jump over a week? In what order is it reading the parameters?

Tested in php: 5.5.4, 5.5.9, and 5.5.10.

The problem occurs only if the startdate is a sunday.

Comment: You cannot mix absolute (`2014-05-11`) and relative format (`last sunday +5 days`)

Comment: Actually you can. strtotime is weird this way.

Answer (score 1):

Since 2014-05-11 was actually a sunday, last sunday jumps one week, since you want the sunday **before** the date specified, when you say "last sunday". You might need a check wheter the absolute date you use is a sunday or not; and act accordingly.

strtotime can act unpredictable here, because you are mixing different statements into one so I suggest something on the lines of

```
echo date("Y-m-d\n", strtotime("2014-05-11 last sunday")+5*86400);
echo date("Y-m-d\n", strtotime("2014-05-11 last sunday")+6*86400);
echo date("Y-m-d\n", strtotime("2014-05-11 last sunday")+7*86400);
echo date("Y-m-d\n", strtotime("2014-05-11 last sunday")+8*86400);
```

You can give the base date to strtotime as second parameter, to make things even more clear:

```
echo date("Y-m-d\n", strtotime("last sunday", strtotime('2014-05-11'))+5*86400);
echo date("Y-m-d\n", strtotime("last sunday", strtotime('2014-05-11'))+6*86400);
echo date("Y-m-d\n", strtotime("last sunday", strtotime('2014-05-11'))+7*86400);
echo date("Y-m-d\n", strtotime("last sunday", strtotime('2014-05-11'))+8*86400);
```

Comment: yes you are correct. 2014-05-11 last sunday will jump into 2014-05-04 and then +5 days means 2014-05-09

Comment: That explains the days up to +6 days, why dose +7 days translates diferent?

Comment: Not sure about that, but I added some suggestions to my answer.

Comment: by using 86400 you falsly asume all days have 24 hours, that incorrect as there usaly one day with 23 hours and one with 25 hour

Comment: That is why I used the phrase "something on the lines of", to give you a pointer, but not the solution per se.

Answer (score 1):

As per PHP.NET [strtotime](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strtotime.php) changelog:

> Prior to PHP 5.3.0, relative time formats supplied to the time argument of strtotime() such as this week, previous week, last week, and next week were interpreted to mean a 7 day period relative to the current date/time, rather than a week period of Monday through Sunday.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4bc6054b173ac81b3fd6ddf535f4fe4bfc06e98f

Test for php versions  > 5.3 and < 5.3, you can see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

@puggan-se Such complexity! It is confusing me and so PHP, let me [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) it for PHP.

```
$sample_date = strtotime('2014-05-11');
$last_sunday = strtotime('last sunday', $sample_date);
echo date("Y-m-d\n", strtotime("+5 days", $last_sunday)); // => 2014-05-09
echo date("Y-m-d\n", strtotime("+6 days", $last_sunday)); // => 2014-05-10
echo date("Y-m-d\n", strtotime("+7 days", $last_sunday)); // => 2014-05-11
echo date("Y-m-d\n", strtotime("+8 days", $last_sunday)); // => 2014-05-12
```

Comment: That was almost how i did it, keept the 2 first row merged, and looped the +days i needed.